# Java library for creating thumbnail from video

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, javacv, xuggle

We are trying to create a thumbnail from a video. We tried two third-party libraries.

Those are

1. https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv
2. http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/

Those are working fine. But we are trying for java built-in libraries. We found a java library, That is

> javax.media.*

But that library is deprecated. We are unable to use it.

Are there any java built-in libraries for this problem?